# paste some character vectors into one string in R

Tags: r, string, paste

I have a character vector of for instance:

```
x = c("a","b","c")
```

and another string that goes like:

```
y = "The alphabet starts with"
```

When I do

```
paste(y,x)
```

I get

```
[1] "The alphabet starts with a" "The alphabet starts with b"
[3] "The alphabet starts with c"
```

But what I want to get is this:

```
[1] "The alphabet starts with a b c"
```

How do I manage to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `paste` twice. `paste` recycles a vector if the length of both vectors does not match. You should first create the vector `"a b c"`, which is different from `"a", "b", "c"`, and then paste it with `y`.

```r
paste(y, paste(x, collapse = " "))
#[1] "The alphabet starts with a b c"
```

Comment: I guess you can use `paste0(c(y,x), collapse = " ")`

Comment: Indeed, good alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using R base:

```
> capture.output(cat(y,x))
[1] "The alphabet starts with a b c"
```